# icon: Upon click trigger action to search

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make the icon click-able so it searches as another option to hitting the "return key". Here is a bootply...http://bootply.com/80297 basically, click on the magnifying glass and it performs the search.

```
                <form class="custom-search-form navbar-search" action="/search" method="GET" >
                    <input name="keyword" class="autocomplete span4" placeholder="Search for an Attraction...">
                    <i class="icon-search"></i>
                </form>
```

Comment: you can add `eventListner` for `click` event then `submit` form using javscript.... `document.form.submit()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also submit the form when you click the image

```
$("i.icon-search").click(function(){
    $(".custom-search-form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<button type="submit" class="bla" onclick="return whateverYouWant();">
       <i class="icon-search"></i>
</button>
```